# Is there a clang-format file for ROS 2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not find a clang-format file to apply the rules found in the [ROS 2 Developer Guide](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Contributing/Developer-Guide/).

Does anyone know if such a file exists somewhere?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325019/is-there-a-clang-format-file-for-ros-2?/) by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2019-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file is embedded in the `ament_clang_format` package which provides the linter API / CLI: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/26397786f603b8e9e4c3c399c3d33b1c6873ee0d/ament_clang_format/ament_clang_format/configuration/.clang-format

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-06-07**:
I don't think it can be applied to our code base, but it is close.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a tool for checking and apply style with clang format called `ament_clang_format` (CLI tool and cmake logic to make it an automated test). However, we do not test against this right now, and I don't think `ament_clang_format` can cleanly apply to our code standard, due to some limitations in clang format w.r.t. to wrapping of arguments.

@mjcarroll was looking at resolving this at some point but never finished.

As @dirk-thomas mentioned we have a style file in that package, but again, if you tried to check our code base with it there would be diff's.

The one we use right now is `ament_uncrustify` which uses uncrustify and a definition file there to check our style. We also use `ament_cpplint` which uses a patched version of Google's `cpplint.py` to do some additional style-like checks.

You can see the list of "default" linters here:

https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/26397786f603b8e9e4c3c399c3d33b1c6873ee0d/ament_lint_common/package.xml#L15-L23

And you can see that for now clang_format is commented out.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2